# HQL query returns a map which does not have the same order as specified in the query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am executing an HQL query like this: (hql query will be dynamic with difrent column names , no of columns , data types )

```
Session session = getSession();
Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery("select a.id as Id, a.name as Name, a.description as Description, a.locationCountryId as LocationCountryId  from AboutUsMaster as a");
hqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List<Map<String, String>> myMapList =  hqlQuery.list();
for (Map<String, String> map : myMapList ){
        System.out.println(map.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
{Name=Test About, LocationCountryId=1, Description=Description, Id=9}
```

In the map I want to get the same order as I'm selecting in the query.
In the query I select `id`, `name` , `description` , `locationCountryId` but in the map I get entries in a different order.

So how to get the same order as specified in the query?

Comment: What version of Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own `ResultTransformer` similar to the one specified by `Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP`. Instead of using a `HashMap`, you'll need to use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the insertion order of the elements.

It could look something like this:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AliasToLinkedEntityMapTransformer extends
        AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(tuple.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
            String alias = aliases[i];

            if (alias != null) {
                result.put(alias, tuple[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTransformedValueATupleElement(String[] aliases,
            int tupleLength) {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to create a class with your code.. AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer . this class is not available.  let me know further. sorry if i am wrong

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? Do you have `hibernate-core` in your classpath? My solution is based on Hibernate 4.3.8, and sure enough, the class should be there: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer.html

Comment: i am using maven. <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
  </dependency>.
hibernate core is in my eclipse build path.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee of order in map.

Refer: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Please allow me to modify your code,

```
for (Map<String, String> map : myMapList ){
    System.out.println(map.get("Id"));
    System.out.println(map.get("Name"));
    System.out.println(map.get("Description"));
    System.out.println(map.get("LocationCountryId"));
 }
```

Comment: sorry i did not mention this in my question.here query will dynamic so i can not take map.get(key).